# Unable to center block element horizontally

Tags: css, reactjs

I am unable to center elements that will be a list of blog posts going forward. The `Postlist` element is loaded into my App.js file. I was able to center the nav bar using the technique mentioned [here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) under the *Horizontally* section and under the subsection titled *Is there more than one block level element?* but when I attempt to do the same technique on the list of blog posts, it doesn't work, bear in mind that the list of blog posts will be dynamic in the future.

*PostList.css* file:

```
.blog-list-container {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.blog-element {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

And *Postlist.js* file:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from '../../App';
import './PostList.css';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Routes,
    Route,
    Link,
    Outlet,
    useParams
  } from 'react-router-dom';

const PostList = ( props ) => (
    <div className="blog-list-container">
        <Router>
                <Link to={'/posts/${}'} className="blog-element">element 1</Link>
                <Link to={'/posts/${}'} className="blog-element">element 2</Link>
                <Link to={'/posts/${}'} className="blog-element">element 3</Link>
        </Router>
    </div>
);

export default PostList
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], consider using a js playground like [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cleaner, shorthand alternative to some of the suggested:

```
.blog-element {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 60px 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

but I would advise using `flexbox` though:

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

While looking at your code and what is mentioned you should consider D.R.Y. when writing components, example:

```
const PostList = (props) => (
  <div className='blog-list-container'>
    <Router>
      {posts.map((post) => {
        return (
          <Link key={post.id} to={post.link} className='blog-element'>
            {post.name}
          </Link>
        )
      })}
    </Router>
  </div>
)

export default PostList
```

Answer (score 0):

It is behaving exactly as you have set the css rules.

```
.blog-element {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto; // will center it to your blog list container.
}
```

Although i would suggest that you set the max-width to the container and remove the width from blog element.

Answer (score 0):

```
.blog-list-container {   
    text-align: center;
}
.blog-element {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 60px 30px;
    margin: 0 auto; // new line
}
```

### Add this line only in your code

or Code like this

```
 .blog-list-container {   
        text-align: center;
    }
    .blog-element {
        display: block;
        padding: 60px 30px;
    }
```